# Firebase RDB presence not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to detect when a player is online/offline, but it seems that while swapping characters all characters stay online until the app is closed, not minimized, or idle but actually closed.

In `useEffect` cleanup `return ()` I can add `userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOfflineForDatabase)` and it will correctly show the character going offline. However, when I close the app and `onDisconnect` is called all characters offline state will get updated again.

So how would I correctly close the connection for a character when it's no longer active?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!selectedCharacter) {
        return
    }

    console.log('selected ', selectedCharacter)
    const dbRef = database().ref('.info/connected')
    const userStatusDatabaseRef = database().ref('/status/' + selectedCharacter)
    const userStatusFirestoreRef = firestore().doc(`characters/${selectedCharacter}`)

    const onOnlineStateChange = snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.val() == false) {
        // Instead of simply returning, we'll also set Firestore's state
        // to 'offline'. This ensures that our Firestore cache is aware
        // of the switch to 'offline.'
            userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOfflineForFirestore, {merge:true})
            return
        }

        userStatusDatabaseRef.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase).then(function() {
            userStatusDatabaseRef.set(isOnlineForDatabase)
            // We'll also add Firestore set here for when we come online.
            userStatusFirestoreRef.set(isOnlineForFirestore, {merge:true})
        })
    }

    dbRef.on('value', onOnlineStateChange)
    return () =>{
        console.log('calling return & close for', selectedCharacter)
        dbRef.off('value', onOnlineStateChange)
    }

}, [selectedCharacter])


let isOfflineForFirestore = {
    state: 'offline',
    last_seen: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}

let isOnlineForFirestore = {
    state: 'online',
    last_seen: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
}

var isOfflineForDatabase = {
    state: 'offline',
    last_seen: database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
}

var isOnlineForDatabase = {
    state: 'online',
    last_seen: database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.info/connected` node is `true` when the client is connected to a Firebase server.  If that happens "while swapping characters", that indicates that the client is still connected to the server. If your use-case requires that the old character gets marked as "offline", you'll have to to this in your application code yourself - as you seem to have done already.

---

> However, when I close the app and onDisconnect is called all characters offline state will get updated again.

Any [`onDisconnect` handlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works) you attach will fire when the server detects that the client disconnected. If you want to cancel an `onDisconnect` handler you added earlier, you can call its `cancel()` method. From the documentation:

```
var onDisconnectRef = presenceRef.onDisconnect();
onDisconnectRef.set('I disconnected');
// some time later when we change our minds
onDisconnectRef.cancel();
```